# Is there a JSX formatter for sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext, reactjs

I'm using Sublime Text as a text editor.

There's a jsFormat for formatting javascript files but I can't find one for JSX.

How you guys deal with formatting JSX?

Comment: Yes, look for the jsx textmate bundle which can be used with pretty much any editor.

Comment: it seems like a syntax hightlighter only, i'm looking for the formatter which does ident and sort of things

Comment: I don't know of one.  The react google group would be a better place to ask.

Comment: can't find a good solution either. Currently it's possible to parse the source with esprima-fb, and use escodegen-jsx to generated formatted output. Formatting options are limited, and you lose white lines... plus escodegen-jsx is a fork without issue tracking.. not sure if it will be actively maintained. I wonder how fb deals with their jsx code base.

Comment: the beta verion of esformatter seem to have some ability of formatting JSX cause it's using esprima-fb, but still not production ready yet

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Update 4**

Check [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier), not that configurable as esformatter, but currently used to format some big projects ([like React itself](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/scripts/prettier/index.js))

**Update 3**

Check [sublime jsfmt](https://github.com/ionutvmi/sublime-jsfmt). If you add [esformatter-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esformatter-jsx) to the config and install the package inside the forlder for sublime-jsfmt. You will be able to format JSX files directly from Sublime. [Here is a guide for that](https://github.com/royriojas/esformatter-jsx/wiki/Usage-with-jsfmt)

**Update 2**

from the command line you can also use [esbeautifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbeautifier). It is a wrapper around [esformatter](https://github.com/millermedeiros/esformatter) that accept a list of globs to format

```sh
# install the dependencies globally
npm i -g esbeautifier

# beautify the files under src/ and specs/ both .js and .jsx
esbeautifier src/**/*.js* specs/**/*.js*
```

**Update**

So I ended up doing a plugin for [esformatter](https://github.com/millermedeiros/esformatter) to enable the formatting of JSX files:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/esformatter-jsx

Here is a [live demo on requirebin](http://requirebin.com/embed?gist=0d67452e01754269660f)

It should be somehow feasible to call [esformatter](https://github.com/millermedeiros/esformatter) from Sublime passing the current file as the argument. In any case to use it from the command line you can follow these instructions:

From the command line it can be used like this:

```sh
# install the dependencies globally
npm i -g esformatter esformatter-jsx

# call it (this will print to stdout)
esformatter --plugins=esformatter-jsx ./path/to/your/file

# to actually modify the file
esformatter --plugins=esformatter-jsx ./path/to/your/file > ./path/to/your/file

# to specify a config file (where you can also specify the plugins)
# check esformatter for more info about the configuration options
esformatter -c ./path/to/.esformatter ./path/to/your/file > ./path/to/your/file
```

**==== old answer below ===**

So if what you're looking is just to make your jsx files to be formatted while allowing the `jsx` syntax (basically beautify all the javascript syntax and ignore `jsx` tags, meaning leave them as is), this is what I'm doing using `esformatter`

```js
// needed for grunt.file.expand
var grunt = require('grunt');

// use it with care, I haven't check if there
// isn't any side effect from using proxyquire to 
// inject esprima-fb into the esformatter
// but this type of dependency replacement
// seems to be very fragile... if rocambole deps change 
// this will certainly break, same is true for esformatter
// use it with care
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var rocambole = proxyquire('rocambole', {
  'esprima': require('esprima-fb')
});

var esformatter = proxyquire('esformatter', {
  rocambole: rocambole
});

// path to your esformatter configuration
var cfg = grunt.file.readJSON('./esformatter.json');

// expand the files from the glob
var files = grunt.file.expand('./js/**/*.jsx');

// do the actual formatting
files.forEach(function (fIn) {
  console.log('formatting', fIn);
  var output = esformatter.format(grunt.file.read(fIn), cfg);
  grunt.file.write(fIn, output);
});
```

I would actually like that esformatter use a version of rocambole that use esprima-fb instead of esprima, to avoid proxyquire.

Comment: This only worked with esformatter-jsx-ignore for me, but that is good enough. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using esformatter-jsx and It works as I expected. However, I also had to add "esformatter-jsx" to "options":{"plugins":{"esformatter-jsx"}} in "Preferences>Package Settings>Sublime JSFMT>Settings - Default" in Sublime 3 to make it works

Comment: This is a great answer, I have this used tool for awhile now, but we have switched to using es6/es7 with babel and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Rkhayat are you sure? latest version of `esformatter-jsx` should support a bunch of ES6/ES7. If there is something not working you can file a bug, and as workaround you can mark blocks that don't work in `/*esfmt-ignore-start*/ code here /*esfmt-ignore-end*/`

Comment: make sure to use the latest esformatter as well as previous ones don't recognize ES6/ES7 syntax

Comment: @royriojas I am using `@Radium `as a decorator, and the linter blows up with "unexpected token ILLEGAL" unless I remove it, also on static propTypes. How do I go about upgrading it?

Comment: @Rkhayat latest version of it handles decorators and class properties as well... https://github.com/royriojas/esformatter-jsx/blob/master/changelog.md#v231

Comment: Does this have to be installed per project? How do I go about upgrading it?

Comment: you can use [esbeautifier](https://github.com/royriojas/esbeautifier)  from the command line and you can also use it in sublime with JSFMT, check this guide: https://github.com/royriojas/esformatter-jsx/wiki/Usage-with-jsfmt

Comment: I believe I followed the instructions for JSFMT / Sublime, the error now states `The formatting failed please check the console for more details` https://github.com/ionutvmi/sublime-jsfmt/blob/master/jsfmt-sublime.py#L64

Comment: check your sublime console, in mac to open the console press ctrl+` you can open a ticket on esformatter-jsx repo or in JSFMT repo with the error you are seeing in the console

Comment: I see that Rdio built (or at least maintained) JSFMT, but since they filed for bankruptcy and got bought by Pandora, I haven't seen progress on the project (last commit Feb 3, 2016): https://github.com/rdio/jsfmt/graphs/contributors?from=2014-03-02&to=2017-03-04&type=c.

Comment: yeah to be fair now I would probably suggest people to use prettier for new projects https://github.com/prettier/prettier, there might be already an addon for sublime.

Comment: prettier does the job for me. sublime plugin here https://github.com/jonlabelle/SublimeJsPrettier and it also has eslint support https://github.com/prettier/prettier#eslint . Glad this question is finally accepted after nearly 3 years.

Answer (score 57):

There is a setting in the HTML-CSS-JS Prettify plugin that allows you to ignore xml syntax in the js/jsx file. That way it doesn't mess up the jsx code.
The setting is: `"e4x": true` in the "js" section of the settings file

Preferences > Package Settings > HTML\CSS\JS Prettify > Set Prettify Preferences

This does not work well if you have self closing tags eg. tags ending in />

Comment: This still works really well with the latest versions of babel-sublime and HTML-CSS-JS Prettify. Just make sure you add "jsx" or whatever file extension you use to "allowed_file_extensions".

Comment: Is this answer outdated? There is not `/>` in my code, but it still does not work

Comment: prettier (aka jsprettier) for sublime is by far the best!! See the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42169688/2178112

Answer (score 20):

You can install a JsPrettier package for Sublime 2 & 3. It's a fairly new JavaScript formatter (at the time of writing this: Feb-2017). It supports most of the latest developments like: ES2017, JSX, and Flow.

Quickstart

1. Install prettier globally using terminal: `$ npm install -g prettier`
2. In Sublime go to Tools -> Command Palette... -> Package Control: Install Package, type the word JsPrettier, then select it to complete the installation.
3. Format your file using context menu inside the editor or bind it to a keyboard shortcut: `{ "keys": ["super+b"], "command": "js_prettier" }`

Links:

- https://github.com/jonlabelle/SublimeJsPrettier
- https://github.com/jlongster/prettier

Comment: This is by far the best answer now! prettier is da bomb!

Comment: Yes, indeed, this worked perfect for me too. Most important thing to notice is the "globally" part.

Answer (score 19):

To add to what @Shoobah said:

> There is a setting in the HTML-CSS-JS Prettify plugin that allows you
>   to ignore xml syntax in the js/jsx file. That way it doesn't mess up
>   the jsx code. The setting is: "e4x": true in the "js" section of the
>   settings file
>
> Go to: Preferences > Package Settings > HTML\CSS\JS Prettify > Set
>   Prettify Preferences

Go to "js" section:

**Add "jsx" to the "allowed_file_extension", and then  change "e4x" to "true"**

Answer (score 16):

the answer in the internet that always told you set 'e4x' to true,
but sometimes, we have to set option of 'format_on_save_extensions' then add 'jsx' in array

modify jsFormat.sublime-settings

```
{
  "e4x": true,
  "format_on_save": true,
  "format_on_save_extensions": ["js", "json", "jsx"]
}
```

Comment: I did as per told by you, but it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: Where is _"jsFormat.sublime-settings"_ found?  so that I can modify `"format_on_save_extensions": ["js", "json", "jsx"]`.  The closest I find about file extensions is: `"js": {
    "allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "json",...]`

Comment: You can find it here: Preferences > Package Settings > jsFormat > Settings - User. Didn't work for me though, still indents JSX weirdly :(

Comment: Have been looking for a solution and this one solved my problem, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Using Sublime's Package Installer, install [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime).  Then:

1. Open a .jsx file.
2. Select View from the menu,
3. Then Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> Babel -> JavaScript (Babel).

Comment: There's also a JSX language package that can be used

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically for Sublime Text, but there is a beautifier in JavaScript for React JSX.

http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify claims to support JSX at:
http://prettydiff.com/guide/react_jsx.xhtml