# Sublimetext 3 not supporting jsx files

Tags: sublimetext3, reactjs

I am using sublimetext3 for jsx files. I have following packages installed with me

1. sublimeLinter
2. sublimelinter-jshint
3. sublimelinter-jsxhint
4. reactJs
5. react snippets

I have `jsxhint` and `jshint` installed using `npm -g` options but still jsx files are not getting supported? Is there anything I am missing or should check on?

Comment: Anyone with any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JSX formatter for sublime text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558699/is-there-a-jsx-formatter-for-sublime-text)

Answer (score 1):

The package you were looking for is [babel-sublime](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel) - Syntax definitions for ES6 JavaScript with React JSX extensions.